# Possible purpose of LINQ select( x => x )

Tags: c#, linq

I'm going through some LINQ examples from a book on MVC and I'm wondering what purpose the select call below could have.  Maybe it's a typo but I don't see any mention of it in the book's errata.

```
foreach( Product p in products
    .Where( e => e.Name == productParam.Name )
    .Select( e => e ) ) {
        p.Price = productParam.Price;
}
```

I tested out two examples of this where the .Select( e => e) was included and one where it was not and the code is the same.  Since Where returns the IEnumerable filtered by the predicate then when would the select call (with the specific predicate above) ever be necessary?  Does it actually do anything?  Could it in some weird corner case?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if you explicitly defined the generic arguments and the return value was an implicitly convertable value from the source. You could also plausibly include breakpoints for debugging (perhaps you would require curly braces and a new line for that though). But other than those (especially since neither of which are _actually occurring_ in the code you posted), I can't think of any worthwhile purpose for it. Perhaps a lazy conversion from Linq query syntax?

Comment: This is actually a common mistake. Even more common is slapping ToList on everything. People generally do not fully understand the execution model of LINQ queries (which is understandable).

Comment: @usr I do wish there was a (standard) `Force` extension though .. there are many times when an evaluation of an IQuerable/IEnumerable must be forced, even if you're not *really* interested in a list. The name would also make it more apparent as to the desired operation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would return the exact same thing as without it, an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx). It's actually doing more harm than good though as it's performing a redundant O(n) operation (looping through the whole list).

**References**

- [MSDN - Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb534803.aspx)

Comment: Not exactly - it will return IQueryable<T>. But otherwise you are correct, you get the same thing as without the Select expression.

Comment: Based on the definition on the Enumerable.Select reference page which is
"Projects each element of a sequence into a new form."
and the fact that the projection is the exact same form, this seems to prove it serves no purpose here.

Comment: @DanielImms if products is an `IQueryable` the select call will end up as an O(1) on most providers because it does nothing. <-- This is just nitpicking. Your answer is good and I upvoted it.

Comment: @usr my argument is that it is calling the lambda expression `e => e` n times.

Comment: @DanielImms IQueryable providers generally do not call the lambda (at all! it is not even executable. It is an `Expression`). They translate to SQL.

Answer (score 7):

> Does it actually do anything?

It does add overhead to the entire operation.  In reality, it should be removed, as it serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I think the author just wanted to show how LINQ queries are very similar to SQL statements.  In this case, it's clearly not needed as it uses the identity function and may be omitted.  However it is a requirement to have the `select` clause in SQL.  It's not wrong to have it there, but it's definitely not needed.

Though in general, having an identity select call isn't always a bad thing, particularly if the query is being returned in a function.  This can help give you a read-only view of a collection you want to return.  But this doesn't apply in this case as the query is being enumerated over immediately.