# ordering of OrderBy, Where, Select in the Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Considering this sample code

```
System.Collections.ArrayList fruits = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
fruits.Add("mango");
fruits.Add("apple");
fruits.Add("lemon");

IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Cast<string>()
    .OrderBy(fruit => fruit)
    .Where(fruit => fruit.StartsWith("m"))                
    .Select(fruit => fruit);
```

I have two questions:

1. Do I need to write the last `Select` clause if `Where` returns the same type by itself? The example is from msdn, why do they always write it?
2. What is the correct order of these methods? Does the order affect something? What if I swap  `Select` and `Where`, or `OrderBy`?

Comment: Can you link to the MSDN whatever that shows that kind of select?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I added additional Where, but question about Select there https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, that example is bogus, as [@BruceJonston](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3121/bruce-johnston) has already answered.

Comment: Considering point 1, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732521/possible-purpose-of-linq-select-x-x

Comment: Filter (where), order (order by), limit (skip/take), transform (select)... unless the transform is required for one of the other steps in which case you would do transform, filter, order, limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No, the `Select` is not necesssary if you are not actually transforming the returned type.
2. In this case, the ordering of the method calls could have an impact on performance.  Sorting *all* the objects *before* filtering is sure to take longer than filtering and *then* sorting a smaller data set.

Comment: and if I use EF, then those impact on performance will take place anyway? Since EF just create SQL query on flow, so can I place OrderBy anywhere then? or after receiving the data L2O will join to make additional actions?

Comment: @sstan What about the ordering of `OrderBy` and `Select` which one should be used first in terms of performance?

Answer (score 5):

The .Select is unnecessary in this case because .Cast already guarantees that you're working with IEnumerable<string>.

The ordering of .OrderBy and .Where doesn't affect the results of the query, but in general if you use .Where first you'll get better performance because there will be fewer elements to sort.